# Could not read config file: No such file or directory: src/main/resources/floodlightdefault.properties

Tags: java, maven, sdn

I am working with the [Floodlight SDN controller](https://github.com/floodlight/floodlight), which is a Maven project.
I am trying to run a`.jar` file that I got by using the `maven package` command.
when I try to run the jar using  `java -jar floodlight.jar`, I get this error:

> ERROR [n.f.core.Main] Could not read config file: No such file or
> directory: src/main/resources/floodlightdefault.properties

The problem is that the application looks for `floodlightdefault.properties` using an absolute path:

> src/main/resources/floodlightdefault.properties

This path does not exist in the jar, but the file itself exists (in the root).

**What I have done so far:**
I confirmed that this is the source of the problem by moving the jar to the correct directory in relation to the absolute path, and it ran from there.

**My Question:**
How can I build this Maven project so that it does not use absolute path with the jar? the project's codebase is large and I do not know where this file is being called. but I think the error is on me as I am a beginner.

Comment: If the app is using an absolute path this is simply wrong. A resource should be loaded via `this.getClass().getResourcesAsStream("/...")`...